# Как узнать текущий статус выполнения DELETE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть t1 в которой 10000000 записей с 2015 года
Удаляем записи по условию где дата меньше 2018 года.

truncate в моем случае не вариант.

delete from t1
where date < '20180101'

Можно ли узнать на каком этапе удаления данных из таблицы, сколько еще ждать?

Answer (score 1):

К сожелению MSSQL не позволяет узнать сколько времени осталось на удаление.
Но это всё же можно узнать пользуясь небольшими хитростями.

1. Надо узнать свой session_id в том коннекте где будет удаление.
   Сделать это можно например так

   ```
   select @@spid;
   ```

или как-то так

```
insert into my_table (my_ses) values (@@spid);
```

2. Надо запомнить текущее к-во строк в таблице, например так

   ```
   update my_table set 
    c1 = (select count(*) from t1 with(nolock)) ,
    c2 = (select count(*) from t1 with(nolock) where условие_удаления)
   where my_ses = @@spid
   ```

Только тогда можно узнать сколько строк удалилось и тому подобное.

3. Запустить в сессии удаление

Теперь к-во строк в таблице можно узнать так

```
  exec sp_spaceused 't1'
```

но это подходит только если вы в базе один работаете с таблицей.

Так же можно узнать статус вашей операции так

```
 select * from sys.dm_exec_requests where session_id = ваша_сессия
```

вы узнаете завершилось удаление или ещё идёт. Поле row_count - будет поазывать сколько удалено. По с1 и с2 можно посчитать % выполнения. По остальным полям можно узнать другие детали. Поле total_elapsed_time показывает сколько времени выполняется запрос.

Так же можно воспользоваться **Activity Monitor** он встроен в оснастку, там есть и session_id и row count столбцы, и ваш запрос который выполняется будет виден.

В зависимости от вашей задачи, вы это можете делать
а) из оснастки
б) можно создать таск для удаления, таблицу, и хранимку или вью которое покажет нужную инфу.
в) используя языки высокого уровня и делая данные запросы высчитать нужную информацию.